# Index & Match formula using IF and ISERROR

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula

I have data in columns C & D. A range of ten students in A1 to A10 are identified with roll numbers. In Column C and corresponding Column D, there are 8 students from roll number 1 to 8 (Column C) and their marks (Column D).

I need a formula in column B to automatically extract the marks from column D against the roll numbers in Column A and the two cells in column B (marks of roll number 9 & 10) may remain blank.

Any Excel formula or VBA macro solution is much appreciated.

```
Column-A     Column-B      Column-C      Column-D
1             50            1           50
2             55            2           55
3             35            3           35
4             60            4           60
5             78            5           78
6             45            6           45
7             39            7           39
8             82            8           82
9
10
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using `VLOOKUP` with `IFERROR`, i.e. this formula in `B2` copied down

`=IFERROR(VLOOKUP(A2,C$2:D$9,2,0),"")`

`VLOOKUP` will return the required marks when the roll number exists.....or an error which `IFERROR`converts to a blank.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest solution would seem to be copy and paste. Alternative solutions would seem to be relatively simple (eg @barry's) but if you really want INDEX, MATCH, IF and ISERROR then maybe:

```
=IF(ISERROR(INDEX(D:D,MATCH(A2,C:C,0))),"",INDEX(D:D,MATCH(A2,C:C,0)))
```

Comment: Using the dynamic features of Office 2019+, MS365 it suffices to enter the following formula into cell B2: `=IF(ISERROR(MATCH(A1:A10,C1:C10,0)),"",INDEX(D1:D10,MATCH(A1:A10,C1:C10,0),1))
`